# Recover data from BLOB file S-Health

Tags: java, android, sqlite, blob

I am trying to get data from a blob file I am getting with the Samsung S-health SDK. 
What I actually do is:

```
Cursor c = null;
int i = 0;
c = result.getResultCursor();

if (c != null) {
    while ( c.moveToNext() ) {
        byte[] live_data = c.getBlob( c.getColumnIndex( HealthConstants.Exercise.LIVE_DATA ) );
        if ( live_data != null ) {

            // Do something with data.


        } else {
            Log.d(APP_TAG, "there is no live data.");
        }
    }
} else {
    Log.d(APP_TAG, "There is no result.");
}
```

"live_data" is a compressed file containing a json with all the data. 
I tried to decompress it with ZipInputStream without success.
How can I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I found the solution after several attempts.
The problem was that the blob file was a gzip file. 
Below is a simple code to decompress the byte array ( in my case live_data ):

```
ByteArrayInputStream inputStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(live_data);
GZIPInputStream gzipInputStream = new GZIPInputStream(inputStream);
BufferedReader bf = new BufferedReader(new 
InputStreamReader(gzipInputStream, "UTF-8"));
String outStr = "";
String line;
while ((line=bf.readLine())!=null) {
     outStr += line;
}
```

Where outStr is the content of the file I wanted to retrieve and live_data is the blob byte array. 
I hope this can be of help to others as well.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried decompression the BLOB file with WinRar? 
I tried for many days this and finally I changed extension to .rar then I got 10x  larger plaintext with data samples (ex.: {"calorie":0.0,"distance":0.0,"heart_rate":89.0,"start_time":1521297002178},)

I have S-Health 5.16.0.043 and older DataViewer1.2.0.apk.